# Alternative string formatter in Python for Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, string-formatting

In Python there is a string fromatter like;

```
>>> print 'Name :%s Surname :%s'%('Ahmet','DAL')
Name :Ahmet Surname :DAL
```

Are there any **native** string formating method in Javascript, which has simple usage as Python has?

**Edited:**
There are methods which is using external library like "sprintf", etc. But I'm just curious, Is there a **native** method in Javascript?

Thank You!

Comment: I've answered this before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639464/javascript-equivalent-to-pythons-format

Comment: Your anwser does not provide a native method usage. You are adding in String prototype yourself. Please read the question exactly. I'm just curious about whether Javascript has a "NATIVE" method for this or not.

Comment: Check out this library https://github.com/zsong/Kiwi - it does what you want but is a lib.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no a native string formatting method in Javascript like `str.format` in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript's [sprintf](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf).

The `sprintf` equivalent example you provided will be:

```
sprintf('Name: %1$s Surname :%2$s', 'Ahmet','DAL');
```

You can also change the arguments' order:

```
sprintf('Name: %2$s Surname :%1$s', 'DAL', 'Ahmet');
```

It is open source and you can download it [here](https://github.com/alexei/sprintf.js).

Comment: Actually, I'm asking for any native method in Javascript like in Python. "sprintf" is not native method in Javascript.