# How to concatenate JavaScript variables into a complexe string with quotes and doubles quotes?

Tags: javascript, twig

```
 var id_person_value = 4;

$('#message').load("{{ path('MyBundle_ajax_modal_vote', {'id_person' :"+id_person_value+"})   }}", function() {//..
```

It should return

```
$('#message').load("{{ path('MyBundle_ajax_modal_vote', {'id_person' : 4 })   }}", function() {//..
```

But this returns me : `http://mywebsite.com/app_dev.php/+id_person_value+`

How could I inject the value correctly?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: try it with 3 brackets like : {{{ path(...) }}}

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of escape characters such as \' to insert single quote inside the string and  \" for double quotes

Answer (score 1):

Instead of concatenating things together, which is tedious and error prone, try a formatting function, similar to `printf` or `format` in other languages:

```
str = format("{{ path('MyBundle_ajax_modal_vote', {'id_person' : {0} }) }}", 4)
```

Unfortunately, there's no such builtin in Javascript, but it's quite easy to write:

```
function format(str) {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return str.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function($0, $1) {
        return args[$1]
    })
}
```

See [JavaScript equivalent of Python's format() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4974238/989121) for more implementations.

Answer (score 0):

use simple double quotes to start and end of string "". If you want to include any quote or double quote in your string use escape character \ before quote
eg you want string as s= hello"world 
then  s= "hello\""+"World"  or s="hello"+"\"" + "world"