# Translate html attribute in django project when returning a html element in javascript

Tags: javascript, django, internationalization, translation, django-i18n

I want to dynamically translate a html button title attribute in my django project using `_("to be translated")` or `{%  trans "to be translated" %}` in a javascript file.

The compilation of the .po files for internationalisation works fine for the .html files:

```
<li data-toggle="popover" title="{%  trans 'to be translated' %}"
```

In my .js file, I return a HTML element from within a function:

```
return $('<button title="{%  trans 'to be translated' %}"  type="button" class="gk btn  btn-default pull-right"></button>').click(onclick);
```

Due to nested quotes `("{%  trans 'to be translated' %}" )` and blanks (`_("to be translated")`) returning a html element from a .js file including a translation does not seem to work.

Is there any workaround for this in django?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Turned out that it was necessary to store the string in a separate variable with the gettext() method.

```
my_var = gettext("to be translated");
```

To insert it into html element that is returned by the function, I used a python-like string-formatting function similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4974690/11598700).

The returned html element looks like this:

```
return $('<button title="{}" type="button" </button>'.format(my_var)).click(onclick);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but if its not important.
You could have that btn. In your html file and just make it hide (something like: css `display:none`.)
and by js or jquery. Just do this:

```
$('#your-btn').attr('title', "{% trans 'to be translated' %}");
$('#your-btn').css('display', 'block');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, this didn't solve my problem. On mouseover, the expression was still visible like this  "{% trans 'to be translated' %}". I just managed to solve it by using the gettext() method in a separate variable and formatting the returned html element (see answer below).

Comment: You could have the templtag code in a var in Js and then paste that vars value to the title.

Comment: <script> var tilte-text = "{% trans 'text to be translated' %}"; $('#your-btn').attr('title', title-text); </script> and be careful about cotations